# Will I hit performance issues if I attach events to each table cell individually?

Tags: javascript, browser, event-listener

It is possible to attach click event to a table and then extract row / column from `event`. So the DOM will have only one listener. This approach is not convenient as we need to parse `event` object and associate the data to the row / column.

More convenient is to attach listener to each cell individually and pass associated data to the callback via a closure. If table is 1000x1000 we will attach 1'000'000 events. I wonder if modern browser could handle it...

Comment: Browser != computer. Browser on 10 years phone will work slower. Better to have one event on parent and than get data from event. This will be much more efficient than having 1mil events just to handle one click

Comment: They can manage 1B events on a page, but it definitely causes slow rendering and more memory usage. I understand managing event delegation in your case will be complex, but it is worth the price.

Comment: Or don't attach events, but do `<td onClick="callback(this)">`

Comment: @Justinas that's probably worse, having to parse 1000000 strings

Comment: So final answer - depends. Paginate your table to reduce rendering and processing load

Comment: *"This approach is not convenient as we need to parse event object and associate the data to the row / column."* You don't have to *parse* anything, just use `const td = event.target.closest("td");` to get the table cell from the event target. (If you might have tables within tables, slightly more rigor might be required: `const td = event.target.closest("td"); if (event.currentTarget.contains(td)) { /*...do your work...*/ })`.) But I'd think a table with a million cells in the DOM is likely to be a performance issue regardless of event handlers, particularly on mobile devices.

Comment: A million event handler attachments are probably doable. However if you meant to attach different functions, i.e. creating a million closures, those need to be considered as well. I would say that browsers definitely can *handle* it, but it's not the optimal solution - it's both slower and uses more memory than attaching a single event handler. However, the real problem would be creating a table with a million cellls - those take memory and rendering time themselves, and nobody will actually read that much content. What data do you need to display, what is the table supposed to achieve?

Comment: Parsing the event object is [quite trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62259593/1169519).

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to attach click event to a table and then extract row / column from `event`.

Yes, quite easily:

```
const cell = event.target.closest("td")
const column = cell.cellIndex;
const row = cell.parentElement.rowIndex;
```